# Prove (by contraposition) that if $a \bullet b = n$, then $a^2\le n$ or $b^2\le n$ ($a$ and $b$ being natural integers)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have seen a similar topic here, but I'm still not entirely sure of my proof, so I'd like to post it here for your review :

Let 
$p : a\bullet b = n$
$q : a^2 \le n$
$r : b^2 \le n$

Predicate to prove :

$p \Rightarrow (q \lor r)$

Contraposion :

$\lnot(q \lor\ r) \Rightarrow \lnot p$
$(\lnot q \land \lnot r) \Rightarrow \lnot p$

**Proof :**

1. $\lnot q \land \lnot r$     *Premise*
2. $a^2>n$ and $b^2>b$
    
   $a>\sqrt n$ and $b>\sqrt n$
   therefore:
    
   $a\bullet b>\sqrt n \bullet \sqrt n$
   $a\bullet b>n$
   Since $a\bullet b$ is strictly greater than n, it cannot be equal to it,  which makes $p$ false
3. $(\lnot q \lor \lnot r) \Rightarrow \lnot p$     *Conclusion from 2*
4. $\lnot(q \land r) \Rightarrow \lnot p$& nbsp;   *De Morgan Law on 3*
5. $p \Rightarrow (q \lor r)$     *Contraposition*

Q.E.D.

Sorry if this is a bit more formal than is used to be seen here, this is the way I have to do it in my class. Also sorry if the english terms are wrong, I learned this in french so I guessed things like 'contraposition' from what I have in french. So, does this make sense?

Comment: I corrected what seemed to by a typo:  You "let r $= a^2\leq n$ which was already covered by $q$.

Comment: @amWhy It was indeed a typo, thanks!

Comment: Your starting premise should be $\lnot q \land \lnot r$

Answer (score 0):

To prove: $ab = n$ $\implies$ $a^2> n$ or $b^2>n$.
The contrapositive is: $a^2<n$ and $b^2<n$ $implies$ $ab \neq n$.
Assuming $a^2<n$ and $b^2<n$ and multiplying the two inequalities, we infer first that $n>0$ and secondly that
$a^2b^2 <n^2$, i.e.
$ab<n$, since $n$ is positive.

Comment: 2 things : 

1. I understand most of your solution, except the last part : how do you get the n > 0 inference?

2. I asked in the question to comment on what might be wrong in my approach, and while it does seem that your approach is similar to mine, it doesn't really tell if it is right.

Thanks

Comment: @amWhy I just realised I wrote the problem wrong in the title : it should read (I edited the title) : "Prove (by contraposition) that if $a \bullet b = n$, then $a^2\le n$ or $b^2\le n$" I'm sorry...

Comment: That's what I was going to point out in this comment.